# using modernizr and css3pie together in ie8 causes visible css3-container text nodes

Tags: fancybox, modernizr, css3pie

it seems if you modify innerhtml of an element, there occurs a race condition that causes rendering of css3-container text node into screen. closest things i could found on the net was this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/M7sZvSFqD5I/Lg9kpNmvkkgJ
http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1531

i had the same problem with fancybox, when i tried to pass html as first parameter.

i tried to solve my problem with this patch to modernizr:

```
diff --git a/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.js b/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.js
index c1a6a9a..0bc0d11 100755
--- a/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.js
+++ b/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.js
@@ -1071,7 +1071,12 @@ window.Modernizr = (function( window, document, undefined ) {
           //   a 403 response, will cause the tab/window to crash
           // * Script elements appended to fragments will execute when their `src`
           //   or `text` property is set
-          var node = (cache[nodeName] || (cache[nodeName] = docCreateElement(nodeName))).cloneNode();
+          var node;
+          if (nodeName == "css3-container") {
+              node = docCreateElement(nodeName);
+          } else {
+              node = (cache[nodeName] || (cache[nodeName] = docCreateElement(nodeName))).cloneNode();
+          }
           return html5.shivMethods && node.canHaveChildren && !reSkip.test(nodeName) ? frag.appendChild(node) : node;
         };
```

but it's too hackish, is there any other proper way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Modernizr 2.5.3 but upgrading to Modernizr 2.6.1 solved the issue.